# PHP count duplicates in text file

Tags: php, file, text, count, duplicates

So I have a text file with a list of games people entered, all on a new like like this:

```
<tr><td>proatowning</td><td>Final Fantasy X</td></tr>
<tr><td>drunkenveteran</td><td>Trials Evolution</td></tr>
```

Now what I would like is some sort of code that allows me to count the duplicates and return them with the amount of times it's been used.

For example:
**5** people submit "Final Fantasy X".
**3** people submit "Trials Evolution".

Then it should return something like this:

```
<tr><td>Final Fantasy X</td><td>5</td></tr>
<tr><td>Trials Evolution</td><td>3</td></tr>
```

This so I can use it in a table. It would be awesome if it could only display the top 10 most voted (most duplicate) games.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you storing the data in some kind of database, or perhaps XML?  I'm just a bit worried you are using an HTML table as storage.

Comment: Well it's a list that gets cleared every week, people enter a game via a text box and is stored into a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this, simply pulling out the second `<td>` tag, checking if thats already in an array, then if it is, add to the count, if not, add an element to the array. then output the array at the end.

```
$lines = file('myfile.txt');
$games = array();

foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $pos = strpos($line,'<td>',8);//start the search for <td> after first one
    $game = substr($line,$pos);
    $game = substr($game,4,-4);//remove the <td> tags
    foreach($games as $name => &$count){
        if ($game == $name) $count++;
        else $games[$game] = 1;
    }
}
foreach($games as $name => $count){
    echo "<b>".$count."</b> people submitted \"".$name."\"\n";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it shows nothing.

`<tr><td>proatowning</td><td>Final Fantasy X</td></tr>`
`<tr><td>proatowning</td><td>Final Fantasy X</td></tr>`

Comment: I haven't tested this out, you'll probably need to make a few changes, but this will get you started in the right direction. If it shows nothing, then there's probably a syntax error.

Comment: Yea but I belief this is what I was looking for, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I have rewrote and simplified the code from Optox answer and it worked for me:

```
$lines = file('myfile.txt');
$games = array();
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $pos = strpos($line,'<td>',8);//start the search for <td> after first one
    $game = substr($line,$pos);
    $game = substr($game,4,-4);//remove the <td> tags
    if (array_key_exists($game,$games) $games[$game] += 1;
    else $games[$game] = 1;
}
foreach($games as $name => $count){
    echo "<b>".$count."</b> people submitted \"".$name."\"\n";
}
```